# Fry's FR-300 USB Wlan Driver

Tags: installation, networking, drivers, usb, firmware

I have been searching all over the internet but I can't find any clues to where I could find a Fry's FR-300 USB Driver. (If it exists)
When I run lsusb The vendor and product # is 07d1:3304.

I can't find anything for it, and the closest thing I have found is: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.general/388385

I'm not sure what I'm doing at this point so I can't install the firmware files or driver to test his find yet. Can someone either help me out or link me to somewhere that would explain the process of installing these, or possibly a proven working driver?

Answer (score 1):

This reply is not the final answer, just plenty of clues & leads to help you out!

I have the Fry's FR-300USB adapter inserted, which I cannot use whatsoever. I also have a second, nearly identical USB Wi-Fi adapter inserted. That one works great the moment it is inserted into a USB port. All you have to do after inserting that adapter is just simply enable it under Network Settings.

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit version, on a Pentium dual-core based PC with 4 GB of memory and the Intel G33 motherboard chipset. When the Terminal is opened and one types in the lsusb command, the following lines show up:

```
casey@casey-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 045e:007d Microsoft Corp. Notebook Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 07d1:3304 D-Link System
```

The last two lines identify the two separate USB Wi-Fi adapters. Both adapters contain the same identical chipset: the RTL8191SU from Realtek Semiconductor Corporation. The drivers are loaded for both adapters and are programmed to recognize the device with the USB ID (shown when one issues the `lsusb` command in the Terminal) of 0bda:8172. So, now one needs to figure out how to add a patch to the drivers so that the device with the ID code of 07d1:3304 gets recognized the same way.

The device that shows an ID of 0bda:8172 when one issues the lsusb in the Terminal gets recognized by the built-in drivers immediately. Just add a simple patch to the drivers already included so that the driver code can treat the hardware device with the ID code of 07d1:3304 exactly the same way.

Once that answer gets figured out, anyone with Ubuntu 12.04 should be able to use the Fry's FR-300USB adapter easily.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-February/392634.html) a thread that describes getting it working.  It's not worth copy pasting the chain of emails from the mailing list.  It links to the same page you found.  Essentially it's newer than the standard wireless drivers, but can be supported by tweaking/recompiling some things:

```
r8712u.ko , which contains support for several chipsets, including the
RTL8192[SU]_USB.
```

The only really significant change from that thread is that the yum line becomes:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so much easier to just grab install ndis and install from the drivers they provide, a bit easier depending on your're computer situation. hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend editing this answer to explain in detail *how* to do this.